# Is legal using iMac garageband sound for my iphone game effect and sound?

Tags: iphone, audio

Hi i am indy developer .

as you know many of indy developer had tiny resources to use.

so i decide using garage band for my app

but i was frustrated what is this right thing ?

if i make sound and effect using garageband and it's preset or resources

it's legal to use?

Comment: Please avoid asking "legal advice" questions on SO. (It may be more appropriate for Programmers SE, which I do not frequent.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.  Apple's sounds effects are royalty-free.

---

> i. GarageBand/Jam Pack Software. You may use the Apple and third party audio loop content 
>       ("Audio Content"), contained in or otherwise included with the GarageBand/Jam Pack Software, on a 
>       royalty-free basis, to create your own original soundtracks for your video and audio projects. You may 
>       broadcast and/or distribute your own soundtracks that were created using the Audio Content, 
>       however, individual samples, sound sets, or audio loops may not be commercially or otherwise 
>       distributed on a standalone basis, nor may they be repackaged in whole or in part as audio samples, 
>       sound libraries, sound effects or music beds.

(from the [iLife SLA - Software License Agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/iLife11.pdf))

Comment: Good question, good answer.  I had actually been wondering the same thing myself.

Comment: That actually says the exact opposite: "nor may they be repackaged in whole or in part as [...] sound effects".

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I understood it as you cannot distribute the sound effects as a audio file alone; however, they can be used as part of another project.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SamBaumgarten: I am not a lawyer. This is where you hire one to double-check, lest you be sued.

Comment: Thanks you all, It maybe not appropriate question in this FAQ but many of programmers will mouth watering at this topic.